# Remote debugging under Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, remote-debugging

Anyone have documentation/tips/tricks/advice on how to debug an application from another computer? I have a MacPro (10.6.1) and a MacBook Pro (10.5.8), and I'd like to debug an application residing on the former from the latter. Both are running XCode 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive Apple document on remote debugging can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/remote_debugging.html).

**Update**: Remote debugging is no longer supported under Xcode 4. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695280/how-can-i-do-remote-debugging-in-xcode-4).

Answer (score -1):

Basically, both the host and client machines must be using the SAME path to the project files. I typically use /Users/Shared/ProjectName on both machines. Either setup a copy script to send the latest changes to the project on each build to the client or if on a fast LAN just mount the client and open the project from the host so both will see the same sources.

Then create an executable in your project and setup the remote debugging settings for the client.