# How to do remote debugging of Mac desktop apps

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, lldb

I'm trying to debug a library that I've written in C++ using XCode 4.6.

My library works properly on my development machine, but crashes when I run it on my target machine (which uses OS 10.6.8).  I'd like to try debugging the code remotely, i.e. by attaching the debugger on my dev machine to a process running on the target machine.

An [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8650634/765287) says that remote debugging isn't supported by XCode 4.6, so I guess I'd need to do it from the command line.

Could anyone walk me through how to set up a remote debugging session between two Macs, assuming this is possible?

Comment: If installing X-Code on the remote Mac is an option for you, you could install an app like ScreenHero on both Macs, and then do your remote debugging via screen sharing.  That would probably be easier than trying to get remote debugging to work across the Internet.

Comment: I've got XCode installed on the remote machine, and I can screen share with it. What next?

Comment: Compile your program on the remote machine, and run/debug it the same way you would on your local machine.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In other words, instead of doing remote debugging (i.e. using the debugger on my dev machine to debug a process on the target machine), just do regular debugging on the target machine.  This is my backup plan. I'd like to avoid it if possible, since it would involve setting up my whole development environment on the target machine, which would be a pain, but in my case it's certainly a possibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts at getting remote debugging to work, I eventually gave up and took Jeremy's suggestion.  I installed XCode on my target machine, recompiled my library there, and then debugged it locally.